# Dynamic vlookup in excel with external file path

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm a formula to calculate data `=VLOOKUP($A3,'\\report\DReport\2566\202301\1cxv\[20230102_io.xlsx]sbia_io'!$B$10:$BK$277,55,FALSE)`

I want to change the name of folder (202301) and filename.xlsx (20230102) with dynamic sheet number (date 01-31). Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot.

I try this `=VLOOKUP($A2, INDIRECT("'\\report\DReport\2566\202301\1cxv\20230128_io.xlsx]sbia_io'!$B$10:$BK$277"),55, 0)`, but it does not work.

Comment: What part "does not work"? Try testing the indirect() first, once that works the put it into the vlookup().

Comment: INDIRECT will only work if the source file is open.

Comment: not much 'dynamic' with the function you're using - I think comments address your query but I've provided below for completeness. best, J

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot(s) refer -- per comments, assuming the resp. file is open, use indirect:

```
="'"&I3&"/"&I4&"/"&"["&I5&"]"&I6&"'!"&I7
```

[image: indirect function]

You'd then place this in the vlookup (in my case I didn't feel like creating this filename/directory tbh, so you'll see my function return a hash ref ! - not because its closed, but because it doesn't exist in first place!#

```
=VLOOKUP(C3,INDIRECT(J7,1),I8,FALSE)
```

[image: vlookup with indirect]

Specifically then:

[image: sample 1 - indirect]

[image: sample 2- with vlookup]

PS - I tested with local files it works / only if the other file open as mentioned.

PPS - you through me off with 'dynamic sheet number' - the example given didn't tie back to your function which included a non-numerical sheet name.  So assume you're referring to 'sheet name' without other razmataz.

ta